# Hide dots when all divs/slides are visible - Owl carousel 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

everyone!

I have dynamicaly generated owl carousel items and i could often have the situation in which all items in the carousel can be visible on the high resolutions. In that case i dont need that one "dot" showing below the carousel.

So for e.g. i will have 4 items and all four of them will be visible on the desktop resolution and in that situation i dont need that one slide dot. but i will need the dots for smaller screens because smaller resolutions will display only 1 or 2 items per slide. but there could be situation with more than 4 items in the carousel (4 per slide max on big resolution) and in that case on big resolutions i will need the dots below.

Is it possible to set owl carousel2 to hide dots or nav buttons when all divs inside the carousel are visible. i couldn't find that feature in documentation and i have also looked here about this topic but couldn't find the answer.

If this feature is not supported already, can anyone help me how to make dot dissapear when all items in the carousell are visible?

thx

Comment: "I have dynamicaly generated owl carousel items"  ... using server-side code?

Comment: You'll probably want to use a callback on init and create a function to count slides, then apply CSS to hide the nav dots. Please make an effort and come back with a more specific question.

Comment: yes, not my part of development but items are generated using server side

Comment: @isherwood  thx for the suggestion, i guess i will try to do something like you suggested.  for "...more specific question", i didnt put enough info in the question or? the thing i wanted to know is simple, i wanted to know how can i hide dots when all items are visible. i am using owl carousel mostly because of smaller screen resolutions. on full size web, i will not have the need for dots most of the time. thx again for your suggestion

Comment: that `one dot` is a kind of micro interaction that tells the user that they are on the only page, removing it is removing feedback that there is no more to show, it is there for a reason.

Answer (score 4):

You can add options to the responsive calls to remove the navigation

See below for example from Owl Carousel 2 docs

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
            nav:true
        },
        600:{
            items:3,
            nav:false
        },
        1000:{
            items:5,
            nav:true,
            loop:false
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I don't think this is solving the problem : to hide dots when there is only one dot (total number of items = number of items by page) you can use the only child selector in a callback : $( ".owl-dots .owl-dot:only-child" ).hide();
https://api.jquery.com/only-child-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-events.html) you could use the following initialization. On the `onResize` you can have a callback. The argument of the callback has an object with data that tell you how many pages the carousel has.

So you can determine if there are more than one pages you can turn on or off the dots and implement the following.

```
var callback = function(e) { 
    var owl = $('.owl-carousel').data('owlCarousel');

    // This is something I found on the documentation but it does not seem to work
    var hasDots = e.page.count > 1; 

    owl.options.dots = hasDots;
    owl.update();
    owl.refresh();
}

$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    dots: true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    },
    onResize: callback
});
```

Unfortunately, although the documentation mentions that each callback is called with an argument, in my tests the `e` argument is always undefined.

So I used a different approach to determine if there are more than one pages. In my demo, the carousel has 4 items and in my initialization I set that when the width of the page is more than 1000 the page size is 5.

So the arbitrary rule that when the width of the page is more than 1000px the carousel has only one dot and in that case you can disable them.

```
var callback = function(e) { 
    console.log(e); //this is undefined :(
    var owl = $('.owl-carousel').data('owlCarousel');

    var width = $(document).width(); // apply arbitrary rule
    var hasDots = (width <= 1000);
    console.log('width: ' + width + ' hasDots: ' + hasDots); // debug purposes

    owl.options.dots = hasDots;
    owl.update();
    owl.refresh();
}

$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:4
        }
    },
    onResize: callback
});
```

A working demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zssffte9/4/):

P.S.: I know my answer is not complete, but it might help you to make your example work.

Comment: Your second approach is great for width different than the one preset by the responsive object properties.
Why don't you simply toggle the dots property on/off this way :
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:4,
            dots: false
        }
    }
});